# Adding distinct $n$ elements separates the elements from a multiset

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Let $K$ be a field or an abelian group. Let $M$ be a multiset of $n$ elements from $K$, or a sequence of $n$ elements $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ from $K$. Let $S$ be a usual set of $n$ (distinct) elements from $K$. Is it always possible to separate the elments from $M$ by adding some elements from $S$? I.e, exist a sequence of $s_i\in S$ such that $a_i+s_i$ and $a_j+s_j$ are pairwise distinct for all $i\neq j\in \{1,...,n\}$.

Note that the elements $s_i$ that I picked from the set $S$ need not be pairwise distinct. E.g., say the elements in $M$ are pairwise distinct: $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. Then I can just pick one element $s\in S$ so that $a_1+s,a_2+s,...,a_n+s$ are still pairwise distinct.

I can see this from example on $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Using the total orders on them, we can easily prove this claim. But for an aribitrary field or an abelian group, I could not formulate the proof nicely. Or is there a proof avoid using the total orders on the field.

Comment: are the proofs really relying on the order(btw which order in $\mathbb{C}$?) or on having arbitrarily many elements?(more like you have a lot of elements so(order here) you take big numbers or distant numbers and hope for the best). Are your fields allowed to be finite?

Comment: @Phicar Well, the problem is when we add stuff. The things migh collide. So I used order to ensure they are all distinct. The lexicographic order on $\mathbb C=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true, if you allow $(s_i)_i$ to be non-injective.

We will prove a slightly stronger statement. Suppose $G$ is an abelian group, $(a_1,\ldots,a_{m})$ is a sequence in $G$, $S\subseteq G$ has $n$ elements, while $F\subseteq G$ has $n-m$ elements.

Then there is a sequence $s_1,\ldots, s_m$ in $S$ such that $s_i+a_i$ are distinct and not in $F$.

Proof by induction with respect to $m$:

- The case when $m=0$ is trivial.
- Fix any $m>0$. Then $S$ has more elements than $F$, so by pigeonhole, there is some $s_{m}\in S$ such that $a_{m}+s_{m}\notin F$. Let $F'=F\cup \{a_{m}+s_{m}\}$, and let $M'=(a_1,\ldots, a_{m-1})$. Proceed.

Your conjecture is the special case when $m=n$.

---

You probably already got it, but here is the argument for an injective $(s_i)_i$ in the case when $G$ admits a compatible linear ordering.

Choose one, then without loss of generality $a_1\leq a_2\leq\ldots,\leq a_n$ and $s_1<s_2<\ldots<s_n$. Then it is easy to check that $a_i+s_i<a_j+s_j$ when $i<j$.

---

Both proofs work even if $G$ is not abelian. In the case of the first proof, it is even enough for $+$ to be injective in the second argument.

Comment: What does it mean to be injective?

Comment: @CO2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function